# Geometric properties of variety/scheme vs. algebraic properties of the coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, big-list, affine-schemes

I am looking for a list comparing the geometric/topological properties of an  affine scheme $X \simeq \text{Spec}(R)$ with the algebraic properties of the corresponding ring $R$ and vice versa.

Particular emphasis should be placed on affine $K$-varieties to make the geometric picture clearer.

An example of this would be:

- An affine $K$-variety $X$ is irreducible iff $K[X]$ is an integral domain. eg. $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x)$ is an ID and consists of only a single curve, whereas $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy)$ is not an ID and consists of the union of two curves.
- the classical points of an affine scheme $X$ lie dense iff $R$ is [Jacobson](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01P1)
- An affine $K$-variety $X$ has no "thick subschemes" iff $K[X]$ is reduced. Where by a "thick subscheme" I mean something like the thick $y$-axis $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2)$ as opposed to $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x)$

As suggested by the examples I am not looking for ultra precise statements on the geometric side of things, but rather one giving justification for either why certain algebraic properties of rings are worth studying or why certain geometric properties are worth studying.

If possible (or you feel the need) please provide an illustrative example (as for instance in my first example)

If possible (as for instance in my second example) a proof or link to a proof or resource is appreciated. In any case, please provide some explanation, or why you think of algebraic property Y giving geometric property Z.

If, in order to describe the geometric properties, you use non-standard language (as for instance in my third example) please explain.

---

Finally, maybe think of the question like this: You read about some new class of rings and ask yourself "Why does that definition make sense? Why should those rings be interesting?" This question should be one place to look for in seeking an answer as, in the geometric setting, the importance may become more clear.

Comment: This might be too pedantic, but your last bullet point is a bit wrong. E.g. $\mathbb{R}[x,y] / (xy, x^2)$ does not contain "thick lines"; but a "thick point". Maybe, *has no thick subschemes* would be better?

Comment: Good point ----

Comment: Maybe one more example: Isomorphisms of varieties preserve irreducibility (and hence whether the coordinate ring is an integral domain).

Comment: Smoothness also seems to be a very geometric property (even though to make it rigorous one probably needs algebraic statements). Anyhow, this property translates to many algebraic statements (evidently, as the definition is already algebraic, so maybe this doesn't count as an example...). E.g. for a local, Noetherian $R$, the property "$1$-dimensional regular ring" translates equivalently to "DVR or $1$-dim UFD or $1$-dim normal domain, or PID but not a field". That's a bunch of algebraic statements! (See Gathmann's notes on commutative algebra in the section on valuation rings for this.)

Comment: This question is much too broad and should be closed. Unfortunately, this is not possible while there's an ongoing bounty.

Comment: I agree that it's a broad question but why should it be closed? I think it's a great question to motivate the study of algebraic geometry.